# where am I going wrong with this IF statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

Would like to know what I am doing wrong with this formula,  It should only return 2 results and it is driving me mad any help of course would be gratefully received.

```
=IF($C2="","",IF($Z2="Ongoing","",IF($M2<>"Declined","",IF((OR($AX2="",$AZ2="",$BB2="")),"DMF Not Complete","DMF Complete"))))
```

Comment: You actually have three results though, `""`, `"DMF Not Complete"`, and `"DMF Complete"` it seems.

Comment: the plan is to only populate the cell if=IF($C2="","",IF($Z2="Ongoing","",IF($M2<>"Declined",""  is met  and then if IF((OR($AX2="",$AZ2="",$BB2="")),"DMF Not Complete","DMF Complete"))))

Comment: My guess as to what you want: `=IF(OR($C2="",$Z2="Ongoing",$M2<>"Declined"),"",IF(OR($AX2="",$AZ2="",$BB2=""),"DMF Not Complete","DMF Complete"))`.

Comment: Remove one extra parenthesis from OR condition